# Showing set is countable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

**QUESTION**

Let $(S,\phi,P)$ be a probability space such that all singleton sets are events. Show that the set $C=\{s \in S: P({s})>0\}$
is countable.

**My ideas**
I don't know how to start with this. I though of infinite null elements, since $\phi \in S$,taking their union with all the $\phi$ can give me countable set.However there is condition $P(s)>0$, so I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

For $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, let $C_n=\left\{s\in S\mid\Pr(\{s\})>\frac1n\right\}$.

If $C$ is uncountable, some $C_n$ is infinite, but then $\Pr(S)=\infty$.

Comment: why did u define pr({s})>1/n and what do you mean by Some Cn is infinite?

Comment: @noob If $\Pr(\{s\})>0$ then for some $n$, $\Pr(\{s\})>\frac1n$.  If each $C_n$ is finite, then $C$ is countable.